# What is a volt?

Tags: electric-field, measure

How a volt is measured and defined in the simplest terms? What does it mean when you measure voltage using a voltmeter? In the past, we defined things by physical things.  For example, the kilogram was defined by a shiny ball we arbitrarily said was a kilogram.

According to NIST the volt was defined by the Watson cell up until the 1970s. As with the other SI units we started moving towards using the constants of nature to define our units. We use quantum voltage by the Josephson Effect. Shooting microwaves between superconductors separated by a thin insulator.

I understand voltage as the work done by moving 1 coulomb of electrons. So 1 joule of work per 1 coulomb is 1 volt. So my question is how is one joule measured? What does it mean?

The water pipe analogies fall short. It’s like pressure in a water pipe. Sure, but if you look at it more closely, it starts to fall apart. The electrons have a set speed. More voltage doesn’t mean they move faster. A higher density just means more amps. Where is this “energy” difference coming from? It’s not more electrons. The closest thing I read was the electric field. But how does that make sense? You can’t change the electron to be “stronger”. A stronger field just means more electrons (amps) in my mind. So what is this joule in volts?

To put it another way what’s the difference between a 1 amp battery at 12 volts (joules) versus 1 amp battery at 100 volts (joules). They both have the same amount of electrons passing through per second. It’s 1 amp. How is one “stronger” than the other?

I have done some research. This question has been asked a few times here, but never answered satisfactorily. Most of them just use circular reasoning to me. It’s really frustrating. One idea I had was to look up how it was measured and defined. The problem is it now uses quantum mechanics. There’s no hope for me to understand that. I appreciate your help.

- https://www.nist.gov/pml/history-nist-quantum-voltage-standards/1970s-history-nist-quantum-voltage-standards
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephson_voltage_standard
- [What, exactly, is voltage?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/517753/what-exactly-is-voltage)
- [If watts is power and amps is current, what is volts](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/63729/if-watts-is-power-and-amps-is-current-what-is-volts)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/274647/what-exactly-is-a-volt

Comment: A joule is measured in as many ways as you can imagine. Canonically, it's the energy required to accelerate a 1kg mass at 1m/s^2 over a distance of 1m, but the relationship 1 J = 0.239 cal is nicer in some ways, because you can almost always turn any form of energy into heat!

Comment: The water analogy doesn't fall apart here: water molecules have a set speed (the speed of sound, a statistical distribution (Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution, unless it's different specifically for water, I don't know, water is weird), but it's the bulk velocity (flow) that matters anyway, not the motion of individual particles. And the flow through a restriction, from high to low pressure, develops exactly the same relations (Ohm's law V=IR, Joule heating P=VI).

Comment: @hobbs the joule as defined by the heat generated during boring canon barrels.

Comment: Correct, electrons have a set speed, nearly the speed of light. But they run around "**in circles**" until some electric current is flowing. This current is "displacing the center of the circles", in average, but comparatively very slowly.

Comment: I think your question is about the intuition around what a volt means, rather than the technicalities of how it's defined, and related back to fundamnetal units. Is that correct?

Comment: A volt is the amount of potential/voltage which causes 1 coulomb of charge to absorb/release 1 joule of energy when it crosses it. 1 joule is the amount of energy that accelerates 1kg of mass from rest to sqrt(1/2) m/s. Or the amount of energy that accelerates 1kg of mass by 1 m/s/s over a distance of 1 m. Though my favourite way to visualize a joule is it's the amount of energy released by dropping an apple from waist height.

Comment: *The electrons have a set speed. More voltage doesn’t mean they move faster.* <-- incorrect; [drift velocity is proportional to voltage](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/494452/20218)

Comment: @Neil_UK Yes, I want to understand what a volt is. I thought if I understood how it was measured it would give me the answer. I'm not necessarily concerned with how it's measured and what unit it is but where it comes from.

Comment: @Andyaka at first glance that would make a lot of sense. If a stronger electric field makes all the electrons move faster than I could see where the volt would come from. But the problem is we already have a unit of measurement called amps. If I have more electrons moving faster I just have more amps. So what is a volt? Other units of measurement just makes sense. Amps count how many electrons pass per second. A second is defined by how many times a cesium atom vibrates. Heat is measured by how much something vibrates.

Answer (score 2):

A volt is a measurement of electrical potential.

I think you need some intuition about what a potential is.

You mention the 'water pipe analogies'. They are in fact a much better place for the beginner to start than the [electron/Drude model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drude_model).

| Hydraulic | Drude |
| --- | --- |
| Potential is baked into the model, right from the start, at a level suitable for pre-schoolers. Don't fall from a height, you'll hurt yourself Higher is more dangerous, more energy. We know that from our third (fourth, 20th?(if you're my son)) bump on the head. | What is potential? What's the very first thing we meet about electricity, before we've met components or electrons? That toy needs a 9 V battery. So what is potential? |
| The force of gravity is **Conservative**. We can therefore use it to describe a potential field. It's easy to visualise, height is potential, especially if you've done your formative 'falling off things'. | Electrical force is **Conservative**. We can therefore use it to describe a potential field. It's not easy to visualise, as it goes round corners with conductors, and if you start thinking about speed of electrons, then you get royally messed up. |
| Current is a flow of water. Water volume is measured in m<sup>3</sup> | Current is a flow of charge. Charge is measured in Coulombs. In copper wire, that charge is carried by electrons, but in semi-conductors, electrolytes, plasmas etc, there are other charge carriers, and carriers of both signs |
| A thin pipe with a flow through it needs a pressure difference end to end | A resistor with a current flowing needs a voltage across its ends |
| Pressure is measured in Pascals. A cubic metre of water flowing through a pressure difference of one Pascal involves one Joule of energy | Potential difference is measured in volts. A Coulomb of charge flowing through a potential difference of one Volt involves one Joule of energy |
| A U-tube with water in it can oscillate, exchanging kinetic energy in the fluid for potential energy of the height difference, while losing energy to viscosity to heat | An LCR circuit can oscillate, exchanging magnetic energy in the L with electrical energy in C, while losing energy in the resistance to heat |
| One way flow through a valve | One way current flow through a diode |
| You can build a DC-DC converter, called a [hydraulic ram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydraulic_ram), that uses an 'inductor' (stores energy as the square of the flow rate) and one-way valve to create high pressure supply of water | You can build a DC-DC converter, called a [boost converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter), that uses an inductor (stores energy as the square of the current) and diode to create a high voltage supply of electricity |
| There are three speed regimes in the movement of water molecules Thermal - water molecules are pinging about with a spread of energies, the higher the speed, the hotter the water Flow - the average speed of molecules down the pressure gradient is flow, much slower than thermal speeds Wave propagation - the speed of sound. This is not the actual motion of the molecules, but how fast a disturbance moves through the volume | There are three speed regimes with the movement of electrons in a conductor Thermal - electrons are pinging about with a spread of speeds, the higher the mean speed, the 'hotter' the electrons Flow - the average speed of electrons along the voltage gradient is flow, much, much slower than thermal speeds Wave propagation - the speed of light (in the medium). This is not the actual motion of the electrons, but how fast a disturbance moves through the space |
| It's [obviously wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_models_are_wrong), wires are not pipes. I see this as an advantage, as when it's time to move on, it's easy to let go of, just retaining the bits that are useful. | It sounds tantalizingly true, so it's far too easy to cling to it, even when you should be moving on |

You may need to recalibrate what you can expect from intuition. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36GT2zI8lVA) is a short video of Richard Feynman talking about intuition and magnetic forces, basically saying that at some point, you will have to fall back on intuition. It's worth 7m 32s of your time.

So, a volt is a measurement of electrical potential.

It can be defined in all sorts of ways. It's the energy per charge movement, when movement occurs, one Joule per Coulomb.

But you know all the details of how to define it and measure it. So you just have to get some intuitive idea that it's potential.

What's the physical process by which electrons get to 'feel' the potential, and so do different amounts of work depending on the voltage of the battery? Now this is not yet expressed as clearly as I'd like, however it's probably on the right track.

What's happening in the hydraulic model? How do water molecules feel the gravitational potential? The water pressure forces molecules together slightly, until they repel each other. Each molecule is therefore being pushed by adjacent molecules. If we put a theoretical surface across the pipe, and remove the water from one side, the pressure on the remaining side times the area of the pipe is the force that flow will move with, through a turbine, or pushing up another column of water.

This gives me a clue as to what's going on in the Drude model. Electrons feel electrostatic attraction and repulsion from other charge carriers. Fortunately, most of the proton and electron charge carriers in the average material are in balanced numbers, in neutral atoms, so we can ignore those effects over scales bigger than a few atoms. The only charge effects an electron in a circuit feels is therefore unbalanced charges, local accumulations or deficits of electrons caused by chemical reactions in a battery, or changing magnetic field through a coil of wire. Consider a battery, with a pair of wires going to a resistor, and consider an electron in that resistor. The force it feels is the summation of all the electrostatic forces between it and all of the locally unbalanced charges around it. Let's say that above it is a positively charged wire, below it a negatively charged one. We can use a shorthand to say that there's an electric field between those wires. The electron's response to that field is to feel an upward force, towards the positively charged wire. the stronger the field, the stronger the force, and the higher voltage we say the battery has.

The electron, or the water molecule, is the same particle, at the same (range of) speed(s), regardless of the potential of the system that's pushing them through a resistor or restriction. The difference is the force they feel that's pushing them through. That force is a direct manifestation of the potential that's driving them.

Note the symmetry between the hydraulic potential and the electrical potential. The hydraulic one is easier to visualise as gravitational potential is just metres, upwards. The electrical one depends on you integrating a complicated 3D arrangement of charged conductors, but the principle is the same.

You could do worse than to look at the [Poynting Vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poynting_vector).

Comment: I absolutely love your comment! I remember a few years ago I went down the why rabbit hole and found this clip. The clip is worth its weight in gold. At a certain point I just have to accept things because it is. If you go down far enough we just don't know. We know what it does and it's properties but what it is... Is for philosophers. I just don't know what a volt is. The unit coulomb and amps explains pretty much everything to me.

Comment: To me the coulomb and amps explain everything. In a circuit you have physical things happening. You can count the electrons. They exist. You can put them in a group and call it a coulomb. If you see that many per second then you have an amp. A stronger electric field means more amps. An electron or coulomb has a set force. What other constant is changing? What makes a 10 volt battery with one coulomb worse than 100 volt battery with one coulomb? In my eyes are both identical. The same amount of electrons and force is passing through per second. What am I missing?

Comment: @Derpy updated my answer with an outline of a physical mechanism that may answer your question.

Comment: So what you're saying is the electric field strength is where the voltage comes from?

Comment: @Derpy Yes, that's right

Answer (score 2):

The Joule is an attempt to quantify energy, the idea of "effort", or the ability to exert effort, to do "work". The metre is easy to describe, you just hold your hands so far apart, and everybody now knows what a metre is. Heat and mass are similarly easy, because they can be demonstrated empirically, but energy (of which the Joule is a measure) is difficult.

Energy seems to be at the root of all of existence, everything that exists is some manifestation of it. "Work" is the transformation of energy from one of these manifest forms to another. A large chunk of scientific endeavour over the last few hundred years has been to quantify it, and the result is a handful of algebraic formulae that tell you how many joules of energy comprise its different manifest forms.

For example, the number of Joules of energy "contained" in a photon of light:

$$ E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$

The energy, in Joules, possessed by a mass due solely to its motion in space (kinetic energy):

$$ E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2 $$

The number of Joules "contained" by an object at rest, due to its mass alone:

$$ E = mc^2 $$

These formulae do not describe any real, tangible thing, but rather they yield abstract values which reveal a remarkable truth about energy - that it's always conserved. That is in any closed system or experiment, when you use them to find all values of all forms of energy in that system, the sum total never changes, even if the forms do.

This is the true importance and meaning of energy (Joules), not that it represents anything on its own (because what it represents can be anything and everything, in fact), only that we are able to predict that if something loses X Joules, then something else gains X Joules.

In other words, conservation of energy enables us to very precisely predict and control the transfer and transformation of energy between various forms, and the meaning of a "Joule" depends on the form it currently holds.

The best I can do to illustrate a "Joule" is to describe its manifest effect  in the context of things you are familiar with, so I'll do that for a few examples.

1. When you lift a mass 1kg vertically upwards through a distance of 1m, the mass has \$ E = mgh = 1 \text{ kg} \times 9.81 \text{ ms}^\text{-2} \times 1\text{ m} = 9.81 \text{ J} \$ of energy more than it had before, in the form of gravitational potential energy. If the muscles you used to lift it were 100% efficient, they would have \$9.81 \text{ J} \$ less chemical potential energy. In other words, they did 9.81J of work, lifting the mass. They are not 100% efficient, so other work will also have been done, mostly in the form of heating.
2. It will take 4200J of energy to raise the temperature of 1kg of water by 1°C. If you wish to boil a litre of water from 25°C, you will need to "deliver" \$ 4200 \text{ Jkg}^{-1}{K}^{-1} \times 1\text{ kg} \times (100-25)\text{K} = 315\text{kJ}\$ of energy to the water. We would say you need to do 315 kJ of work. A 1kW kettle would take *at least* 315s to complete the job, certainly longer due to inefficiencies.
3. A photon of red light has about \$ E = \frac{hc}{\lambda} = \frac{6.6\times 10^{-34}\times 3.0\times 10^8}{700\times 10^{-9}} = 2.8\times 10^{-19}\text{ J}\$ of energy. A 50% efficient 5mW red laser delivers 0.0025J of light energy each second, which would be \$ \frac{0.0025}{2.8\times 10^{-19}} = 8.9\times 10^{15}\$ photons per second.

You asked "how is a Joule measured?". Again, that depends on the form of the Joule of energy. If the form is light, and you know the wavelength of the light, you can literally count photons, and apply the formulae above. Or, perhaps, you could absorb the light into a black light-absorbent material, and measure the rise in temperature of the material. If you want to know how many Joules of energy are stored in a battery, you could make the battery turn a motor to lift a mass. There are other, probably better ways, but you get the idea.

Now onto the Volt. A better analogy than water is gravity, and a ball rolling downhill. At the top of a hill, a ball has more gravitational potential energy that it would at the bottom, due to the gravitational field of the planet. It accelerates downwards because gravity exerts a force upon it. As it accelerates downhill, it loses gravitational potential energy, and gains kinetic energy (velocity - remember, conservation of energy). On its way, it collides and interacts with whatever obstacles it encounters, transferring some of its newly gained kinetic energy to the obstacle. Due to obstacles and other forces at work, the ball is not free to continue accelerating, rather it achieves a sort of "terminal velocity", and by the time it reaches the bottom of the hill, it has expended all the potential energy it began with, arriving with almost no kinetic energy, at a place where it has no potential energy either.

In other words, if the ball starts with 100J of potential energy at the top, almost all of that energy is delivered to the various obstacles on its path, and when it reaches the bottom with (close to) 0J of kinetic energy, and 0J of potential energy.

The potential energy it has at any point on its journey represents the "voltage" at that point. At the top it started with 100J. Half way down, the ball had 50J of potential energy, so we could say the "voltage" there is 50 (the units are messed up in this analogy, but you get the point). At the bottom, the potential (voltage) is zero. It's important to note that you could called the potential energy at the top 100J, 0J or 1,000,000J, as long as it has 100J less at the bottom (in which case you'd say that the "voltage" at the bottom is 0, -100 or 999900 respectively) - everything is relative, and we usually talk in terms of potential differences, not absolute potentials.

For electrons, if the potential at the point where the charge currently finds itself (point A) has a "voltage" (AKA "potential") which is 10V higher than charges at point B, then any charge at point A will have 10eV of potential energy *more* than a charge at point B. On a journey from A to B, that charge will start the journey with 10eV of potential energy, and end with none. All of that energy will have been donated to whatever obstacles it encountered on the way, making light, heat, motion etc.

The electron charge is \$ q=1.9\times 10^{-19}C \$, meaning that you require \$ \frac{1}{1.9\times 10^{-19}} = 6.2\times 10^{18}\$ electrons to have 1 Coulomb of charge. The electron-volt is a unit of energy equal to \$ 1eV = qJ \$ Consequently, you would need \$ 6.2\times 10^{18} \$ electrons (a total of 1C) to make that journey to deliver all 10J of energy to whatever they flow through. Alternatively, twice that number making half the journey would also deliver ("dissipate") 10J of energy, so it's not necessary for a charge to make the entire journey, only that lots of charges to travel some fraction of the distance.

Charges always experience a force in the direction that accelerates them to a place of *lower* potential energy. If there's no potential difference (AKA EMF, voltage) explicitly applied across a circuit or conductor, charges settle into a position of equilibrium, where they all have equal forces left and right, above below etc, with no net force to accelerate them away from that equilibrium. Often that's a uniform distribution of charges throughout the conductor, in which no charge has a higher or lower potential energy than any other. In other words, the potential difference (voltage) between any two points in the conductor is zero.

The only means by which a charge would feel compelled to move, is if it finds itself in a region where charge density to one side is greater than density on the other, resulting in a repulsion away from the higher density region, and an attraction toward the lower density region. Therefore, to compel charges to move, it is necessary to artificially introduce a non-uniformity, which we can do with cells or magnetic fields.

With a cell, we charge it by doing work to ionise molecules, and separate electrons from their parent atoms' nuclei. By grouping electrons to one side, and leaving the now-positively charged nuclei on the other, we have produced a charge imbalance, a dense grouping of negative charges physically separated from a dense group of positive charges, which have no conductive path via which to travel and redress the imbalance. The charges on each side now have a large potential energy. For example, in a 1.5V cell, each charge has 1.5eV of electrical potential energy, experiences a strong force towards its opposite partner, but has no way to travel there.

By connecting the electrodes of the charged cell to an external conductor or circuit, the charge density imbalance in the cell repels/attracts charges in the external conductors, suddenly endowing them also with 1.5eV each. In this way the connected circuit now also has a 1.5V potential difference across it.

The electric field due to the charge separation in the cell is now forcing charges in the connected circuit to move. Starting at the cell, charges with 1.5eV of potential energy can travel out and around towards a place of lower potential energy, eventually returning to the cell with none, the recipient of all that energy being whatever it travelled through to get back to the cell.

I do not agree that charges have a set speed, which does not increase as voltage is raised. Doubling voltage doubles electron drift velocity. If the conductor is purely resistive, then not only will velocity double (causing a doubling in coulombs-per-second current), but the starting potential energy of each charge is doubled. This means that energy-per-second dissipation (power) in the conductor increases by a factor of four, giving rise to the square term in \$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} \$

Comment: I appreciate the post! I understand now that with a higher voltage comes a higher drift velocity. Is that where the volts come from? Let's compare two different circuits. They both have one coulomb of electrons we're moving. If one circuit moves one coulomb twice as fast, does that mean it has two volts? That makes a lot of sense in my head. I don't know if I'm correct. In other words, all the electrons drifting through the circuit going faster per unit (coulomb) is what defines voltage?

Comment: But if that's the case then why not just say I have two amps? Two coulombs are moving per second. So again I don't know where volts comes into play.

Comment: I don't know why something so simple I can't understand. I'm sorry.

Comment: NOOOO! a higher drift velocity means exactly a higher current. Let's dive into this Drude material. A higher electric field, more volts per metre along it, is a higher rate of change of potential along it, is more net force on the electron. This makes them push harder, deliver more energy per unit movement. Their speeds, typically 10^6 m/s thermal, 10^-3 m/s drift rate, are barely altered by the electric field. It's a conceptual nonsense to see this range of speeds and still think that collisions with the lattice do not do anything for thermal speeds, but do for drift speeds. Forget speeds.

Answer (score 0):

Considering voltage as a weight that applies pressure on a physical object like a capacitor plate provides one way to set up an experimental method that just needs acceptance of an accurate measurement of force. This is the principle behind an electrostatic voltmeter, which balances the force between charged plates against the restrictive force of a spring. But this may be complicated by the fact that the voltage between charged plates changes with distance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_voltmeter

Comment: That was one idea I had. If I figured how the tools measured volts it would give me the answer of how it was defined and what it was. More electrons on a capacitor just means more amps or coulombs if they're not moving. How is a coulomb of electrons stronger or weaker? That's what a volt is saying. It's saying for these many electrons, this other system is stronger. What's stronger?

Answer (score 0):

Voltage is always measured relative to some other reference.  Meaning its always measured between two points.

Charges in an electric field experience force on them due to the field.  Therefore, it takes work (measured in Joules) to push them from one place to another in the field.  So as charges move in an electric field they gain or lose potential energy in the same sense that a rock gains potential energy if I lift it in the air by doing work against gravity.

You don't have to get too hung up on what it means for an electron to have more potential energy.  Just think of Energy as an accounting method that adds up all of the net forces applied to an object as it moves from one point to another.  We have countless experiments confirming conservation of energy.  So, if our accounting method shows that we put energy in to move the object, then under certain conditions we can get the exact same amount of energy back to do work for us.

The units of the Volt are Joules per Coulomb.

1 Volt means that if 1 Coulomb of charge were to move between the two measurement points, then it would gain (or loose) 1 Joule of energy.

Note that energy is the integral of force.  So, the force that electrons feel due to being pushed by an electric field is not the same thing as the voltage between two points (it's in fact the derivative).

Though voltage is often compared to pressure, they are different in character.  Pressure measures force per unit area.  In that sense its more analogous to electric field strength.  The work done by something moves due to pressure is more analogous to voltage.

For a constant uniform field force and voltage are proportional, which is where the pressure analogy probably comes from.

Comment: I appreciate the comment. To put put another way, what makes 10 volts and one coulomb different than one volt and one coulomb? That's the heart of my question. The same amount of electrons are passing through. What's changing? What makes it 9 more volts? The more I look into volts, the less it has any meaning to me. Does the higher drift velocity of all the electrons make it a higher voltage? Is that where volts come from?

Comment: What's different is that the integral of the electric field along the path taken is 10X bigger for the 10V case compared to the 1V case.  On average the electrons are experiencing 10X the force, and so can do 10X as much work.  The battery/power supply is the thing creating that field.  Drift velocity does not determine voltage.  How far the electrons move and with what force determines the voltage drop.  Energy = Force x Distance.

Comment: Also note that drift velocity is often very low.  Like 10^-4 m/s in typical cases.  So, electrons leaving a battery at a rate of 1A and going through 1m of wire might take several hours to reach the other battery terminal.  But that's OK.  Its equivalent to have 10,000 coulombs of electrons travel 0.1mm/s instead of having 1 coulomb travel 1m/s.  The force x distance product is the same either way.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense. So what you're saying is the voltage is coming from the electric field from the terminals of the battery? I imagine all those electrons in that small space at the end of the battery (inside) is creating that large electric field that goes across the whole circuit. That field is creating the force on the electrons in the wire. So per coulomb I can see it having more energy just by the force of the field. I remember watching a while back a video by veritasium on how the wire just guides the electric field.

Comment: So the more electrons you have bunched up on the negative terminal of the battery, the greater the electric field through the wire? That in turn creates a force on the electrons throughout the wire. The greater that field, the stronger the electron movement?

Comment: The electrons don't necessarily need to be bunched up on the negative terminal, but electrons need to be displaced somewhere.  The rest of your interpretation is correct.